# A contradiction in the Babinet principle, an even more mysterious phase difference

Tags: optics, waves, diffraction, superposition

[This is a continuation of a previous question I asked.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/706047/a-mysterious-phase-difference).

So, as we know the Babinet principle states that the superposition of the screen and its complement is the same as the **unobstructed light**.

This was all fine and dandy until Wikipedia also went on to say that the phase difference between the complementary systems are $\pi$ [Link].([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babinet%27s_principle#:~:text=In%20physics%2C%20Babinet's%20principle%20states,by%20French%20physicist%20Jacques%20Babinet.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babinet%27s_principle#:%7E:text=In%20physics%2C%20Babinet%27s%20principle%20states,by%20French%20physicist%20Jacques%20Babinet.))

I initially understood the phase difference of $\pi$ as follows:

We have a pattern from screen $S$ and its complementary $S'$, when we superimpose both of them, we have complete darkness as it would be complete obstruction. However, when I thought more about this argument, more it felt absolutely bogus. We are superimposing the light, we cannot just superimpose obstacles, by that logic in YDSE. If one slit was covered and other was not and vice-versa, their superposition is that both are **open**, not both are closed. So, we should superimpose the un-obstructed part of the light, not the obstructed part.

Now, the Wikipedia article on Babinet is exactly contradictory to what i said

> The explanation is relatively simple. Suppose that B is the original diffracting body and B’ is its complement, i.e. a transparent body where B is opaque and opaque where B is transparent. The sum of the radiation patterns caused by B and B’ must be equal to the radiation pattern of the unobstructed beam.

The above statement agrees with my logic that we care about the un-obstructed part, and so the super-position should be completely dark.

However it also said:

> The radiation patterns produced by B and B’ must therefore be opposite in phase, but equal in amplitude.

Doesn't that mean the superposition is completely dark? If that's the case then how is the statement that is below is correct, isn't it contradicting?

> The sum of the radiation patterns caused by B and B’ must be equal to the radiation pattern of the unobstructed beam.

For an obstructed wavefront, it will happily move without any issues, so how did it all of a sudden become dark?

The phase difference $\pi$ seemed a bit slimy and mysterious to me. I don't see a mistake in my argument that the superposition of complementary systems should be the case where there is no obstruction.

Answer (score 0):

The sum of the patterns caused by B and B' is not complete darkness. It is, like the article says, the pattern caused by the unobstructed beam. If you shine a laser beam on a slit (object B) and its complement (object B') for example, the sum of the two patterns on the screen would be just the laser spot. Note that the screen will be dark *outside of this central beam*, meaning the sum of the patterns due to B and B' cancel *except on this central beam*. This is also what the article says, if you include the part you left out in your question:

> **In places where the undisturbed beam would not have reached**, this means that the radiation patterns caused by B and B' must be opposite in phase, but equal in amplitude.

Comment: But isn't the beam infinite cross-section?

Comment: Also, i think the statement says that B and B' are just opposite in phase everywhere, then it's superposition is dark no?

Comment: @AbhiramCherukupalli It depends on what kind of beam or light source you use. For these experiments you often use a laser beam, which obviously doesn't have infinite cross section area. The Wikipedia article also seems to assume a finite beam size. As for your second comment, while maybe the wording could be clearer, like I said I don't see the article claiming that the pattern for B and B' are equal in magnitude and opposite in phase *everywhere* (note my emphasis in the quoted sentence). This is only true in areas that would be dark when the beam is not obstructed.

Comment: @AbhiramCherukupalli Light never cancels itself, that's a violation of conservation of energy ..... complementary Babinet patterns are complementary diffraction patterns and diffraction is best understood by using Feynman. It will likely always lead to contradiction if you use classical wave theory to understand diffraction/interference.